# Roboto Flex и кириллица

Tags: css, web-fonts

Хотел на сайте использовать данный шрифт и столкнулся с проблемой отображения кириллицы.
Насколько я понял, ребята не распространяют официально шрифт в `woff2` формате (что странно для шрифта нацеленного в первую очередь на веб), но в сети нашлось несколько версий в этом формате и при локальных тестах ровно та же проблема.

Для живого примера возьмем [typetools](https://typetools.typenetwork.com/)

[image: Выглядит так]

Не исключаю возможность каких-либо локальных проблем, в свое время уже был баг с оригинальным Roboto, который криво отображался в webkit если был установлен в системе, но Flex на всякий случай удалял для проверки. Проверял на webkit (Win7x64).
Прошу подтвердите наличие бага со шрифтом, или помогите найти проблему.

На всякий случай открыл [issue](https://github.com/TypeNetwork/Roboto-Flex/issues/136) на гитхаб, но пока ответа нет.

Comment: У меня проблема не воспроизводится, подключил официальный ttf — всё вроде бы нормально https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoGhj.png

Comment: В том-то и дело, что с установленным шрифтом проблем нет, макет в люстре и фотошопе отображается идеально с любыми настройками вариативности, а woof2 вариант дает сбой. Для быстрой проверки я оставил ссылку на typetools, там выбираем FAMILY: Roboto Flex, в любом поле печатаем слово "КОНТАКТЫ", для более явного отображения ставим ползунок ползунок  wght на минимум, а wdth на максимум.

Comment: В системе его вроде нет (ну как минимум я его точно не ставил). http://s01.geekpic.net/di-A5NJQZ.png

Comment: Спасибо. Ну что ж, значит проблема шире чем мой ПК... Видимо светлое будущее вариативных шрифтов пока так и остается в будущем. Будем по старинке делать, это был единственный универсальный вариатив что мне подошел.

Comment: @A-off то есть вы не хотите допускать вариант, что это typetools сам по себе сломан? Почему вы вообще зациклились на этом typetools? Проверьте работу шрифта на отдельной самодостаточной веб-странице.

Comment: Я же ясно написал, что "при локальных тестах ровно та же проблема", тайптулс для вас, чтобы быстро проверить.

Comment: @A-off у меня при локальных тестах такой проблемы нет. Какую последовательность действий нужно выполнить, чтобы у меня проблема тоже появилась?

Comment: Принудительно использовать woff2 версию шрифта чтобы не подхватился системный вариант и применить вышеупомянутые настройки вариативности.

Comment: @A-off откуда взять woff2 версию шрифта? Может, просто сам woff2-файл испорченный? Не берите его и возьмите ttf версию шрифта, чтобы решить проблему